# How much Barracks/Gateways does a single CC/Nexus support?

Tags: starcraft-2

Let's say I were to produce a mixed tier 1 unit composition as either Terran or Protoss.

**How much Barracks / Gateways could my CC / Nexus support?**

As I am a Terran player I usually see 3 Rax OR 1 Rax 1 Fact 1 Star on a single base.

But [Day[9] #274](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/4925514/) got me thinking that after producing some early units I could produce reapers in order to get more Rax so that I can do early harassment with all my first units and come out stronger in the middle of the game. But this leaves me wonder, how many production buildings can my CC support when it would be fully saturated? Then, when I have a strong amount of units in the middle game I could easily expand and refill my army.

**But I'm clue-less how to determine the maximum amount of buildings my economy can support.**

If you can generalize this to include higher tier buildings, please do...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree, calculating these kinds of things are tough.

First you have to not calculate what unit producing buildings you need, but rather, what units you're going to build.  For example: you can go 5 Rax Reapers, but only 3 Rax if you're doing a mix of Marauders/Marines.

But ok, you've got some build like: 2:1 Marines/Marauders, how many bases do you need to continuously produce that?  Man, that'd be annoying to figure out for *every* combination of units you'd like to build.

Luckly, you don't have to!

[Protoss](http://sc2calc.org/unit_production/protoss.php),
[Terran](http://haploid.nl/sc2/unit_production/terran.php),
[Zerg](http://haploid.nl/sc2/unit_production/zerg.php)

This will allow you to easily calculate how many bases you need to support the build of X number of type Y units!

Comment: I'd write more, but TSL is on...

Comment: Great links, didn't know about them.

Answer (score 5):

I also suggest you try this soft : http://code.google.com/p/scbuildorder/ which allows you to simulate and optimize your build orders for the 3 races.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the toss side goes one Nexus can support:
4 gateways
Or 
2 gateways and one robo
Or 
2 gateways and one star port